# Labels not parsed in Expss for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, expss

I'm new to R and trying to explore my variables by groups and i'm using a for loop to pass all suiting variable names under expss.

Here is an reproducible example :

```
    require(expss)
    require(dplyr)
    colnoms <- as.data.frame(HairEyeColor) %>%  names(.)
    expss_digits(2)

    for (i in colnoms){      

    as.data.frame(HairEyeColor) %>%
        tab_cells(get(i)) %>%
        tab_cols(Eye) %>% 
        tab_stat_cpct() %>%
        tab_last_sig_cpct() %>% 
        tab_pivot() %>%
        set_caption(i) %>% 
        htmlTable() %>% 
        print()  
    }
```

I expect the name of the variable in the output (Hair, Eye, Color) but instead i get only "get(i)".
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `get` we can not to know original variable name. The simplest way to show original name is to set variable name as label:

```
require(expss)
data(HairEyeColor)
HairEyeColor <- as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
colnoms <-  names(HairEyeColor)

expss_digits(2)

for (i in colnoms){      
    # if we don't have label we assign name as label
    if(is.null(var_lab(HairEyeColor[[i]])))  var_lab(HairEyeColor[[i]]) = i
    HairEyeColor %>%
        tab_cells(get(i)) %>%
        tab_cols(Eye) %>% 
        tab_stat_cpct() %>%
        tab_last_sig_cpct() %>% 
        tab_pivot() %>%
        set_caption(i) %>% 
        htmlTable() %>% 
        print()  
}
```

Comment: Great solution, it worked like a charm! Thank you, Gregory for your fast and reliable assistance.